# How to know what number of local minima and local maxima is impossible for a polynomial function to have?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> How to know what number of local minima and local maxima is impossible for a polynomial function to have?

For example, the graph of the polynomial $p(x)=ax^5+bx^4+cx^3+dx^2+ex+f$ is sketched. a,b,c,d,e,f are real constants and $a\not=0.$
Which of the following is **not** possible?

> A) The graph has two local minima and two local maxima
>
> B) The graph has one local minimum and two local maxima
>
> C) The graph has one local minimum and one local maximum
>
> D) The graph has no local minima or local maxima

I know that A) and D) are possible, but how can I know whether B) or C) is possible?

Comment: The same question was asked few days back in the same forum. It is duplicate question.

Comment: Do you have a link to the question? When I searched for a question similar to mine, I couldn't find anything, so I asked.

Comment: I remember some 10days back it was any way solution will be since derivative will be of degree 4 hence Maxima and minimum will occur in pair i.e either one set of local Maxima and minimum , 2 sets of local Maxima and minimum on none of local Maxima and minimum .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

B) is impossible as the shape of such graph does not matches with the behavior at $\pm$ infinities of a odd degree polynomial.

C) is possible as you can see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+y%3Dx%5E4(x-1))

Also [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function) might be useful for you.

Comment: Thanks! So for an odd function one end is going towards $- $ infinite and another towards $+$ infinite? And for an even function both ends are going towards $+$ or $-$ infinities?

Comment: @ErisTyenns: For an even degree polynomial both ends are going towards + infinity or - infinity, depending on the sign of the leading coefficient.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** If a graph has two local maxima and one local minimum, then the minimum must occur between the two minima. On the other hand, if, say, the leftmost extremum of a (nonconstant) polynomial $p$ is a maximum, then as $x \to -\infty$ we also have $p(x) \to -\infty$. With this is mind, what do you know about the behavior of a polynomial of odd degree as $x \to \pm \infty$?